# windows firewall disabled with Norton Internet security or Norton Smart Firewall?

Tags: windows, firewalls, physical

My Company decide to Change **antiviruses** and **anti-spywares** and **firewalls**.

How to apply changes in all clients and servers safety?

> Norton say: ( in this [article](http://community.norton.com/t5/Norton-Internet-Security-Norton/Norton-Smart-Firewall-vs-Windows-Firewall/m-p/745638/highlight/true#M207078)):
>
> When you are using Windows 7, the Windows Firewall will disabled by
> some third-party firewall, such as Norton security

This is a Windows feature that prevents the accidental running of two firewalls at the same time.

> Microsoft Say: [Here](http://windows.microsoft.com/is-IS/windows/How-do-I-uninstall-antivirus-or-antispyware-programs)
>
> If you use more than one antivirus or antispyware program at the same
> time, your PC may experience decreased performance, become unstable,
> or restart unexpectedly. Before you install Microsoft Security
> Essentials, or if you want to resolve issues with Microsoft Security
> Essentials, including installation issues, you must first completely
> remove any Internet security programs from your PC.

My Question:

> Any tips how to safely remove firewall or antivirus software and install another.
>
> My present firewall or Antivirus software is about to expire and I want to remove
> it and install another.

firewall ask us to block any programs that may be a harmful, and when we uninstall firewall they active to send data.

when we uninstall firewall, what happen? system has no firewall!!! Didn't dangerous for our system's security? Trojans that blocked by that firewall,active again??

if there are any Trojans in the system, damage us.

which way to uninstall one firewall and install another firewall ,safe, Such that Trojans couldn't active? and send any data for hackers?

Is there any way to uninstall and install another one, safety?

If I uninstall Norton Internet security Windows Firewall start automatically again?

Comment: Could you make an effort to type comprehensible English?

Comment: could you correct this? by edit button?

Comment: @sabertabatabaeeyazdi I read your question and answered it the best I could, however it is difficult to understand.  I voted to close because it appears ambiguous.  Just know that if this it is closed, it can be reopened later when it is edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change firewalls either install Norton and setup Norton before de-activating the Windows firewall. This is very unlikely to cause issues, usually conflicts occur when you are running an active scan and one AV picks up on another's signatures or when two AVs are running passive scans and they both try to take care of a suspicious program at the same time.

If you want to be extra careful then just disconnect the internet, then turn off the Microsoft software and install and configure Norton prioir to re-connecting.

Personally though I'd stick with the Windows firewall if you have Windows 7 or newer as it is very good and easy to use.

Comment: my another question is : is it secure? when we can not apply it suddenly? for example turning off or turning on the Microsoft software (firewall) suddenly (abruptly) in 700 PC impossible. because apply with GPO , or install and configure Norton apply with GPO in Active Directory. that take a long time like transpiration.

Comment: In that situation I'd apply, update and configure Norton and then disable the MS software afterwords. However the firewall at your gateway should take care of most traffic on a corporate network, the software firewall on the individual PCs is more of a second wall of defence.